# Check if object is an instance of a group of classes

Tags: python, class, scikit-learn, instance, statsmodels

I have an object, and it is either

- `statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLMResultsWrapper`
- `statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper`
- `statsmodels.base.elastic_net.RegularizedResultsWrapper`

or

- `sklearn.ensemble._gb.GradientBoostingClassifier`
- `sklearn.ensemble._forest.RandomForestClassifier`

I am trying to use `isinstance()` to like below:

```
if isinstance(my_obj, statsmodel_type_class):
   do sth
elif isinstance(my_obj, sklearn_type_class):
   do sth
```

I can hard code `statsmodel_type_class` and `sklearn_type_class`. But are there any "Base" class for each of these two type of classes?

Comment: You can pass a tuple as the second parameter to `isinstance()`, to check if the object belongs to any of the specified classes.

Answer (score 0):

`statsmodels` and `sklearn` classes are not subclasses of each other in the sense you're asking, so no. If you want to do different things depending on each type, the if statement is a good first choice. If you want to do the same thing for both instances, you can simplify code using a tuple:

```
if isinstance(my_obj, (statsmodel_type_class, sklearn_type_class)):
   do sth
```

as suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance).